# detecting idle kafka consumer or container?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

hi there I am using kafka with spring in order t consume some messages using the code below:

```
public ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String> newContainer(String topic, int partition,
int idlePeriod) {
this.factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory);
this.factory.getContainerProperties().setIdleEventInterval(idlePeriod * 1000L);
this.factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String> container = this.factory
    .createContainer(new TopicPartitionOffset(topic, partition));
container.setupMessageListener((AcknowledgingMessageListener<String, String>) (record, acknowledgment) -> {

kafkaService.proccessorConsumer(record);

acknowledgment.acknowledge();

});
this.containers.put(service_name+"test", container);
container.start();
return container;
}

@EventListener
public void idle(ListenerContainerIdleEvent event) {
log.warn("Idle period has been captured", event);
kafkaService.processIdelConsumer();
}
```

I used the property "setIdleEventInterval" in order to capture an event when no data has been consumed for a while to do some processing
what I am not sure about is the meaning of  idle container... is it mean that no data has been produced to the topic or it means no consumer has consumed from this topic ...and info please about the specific meaning of idle container ... I have done some research but still not sure about it .

Answer (score 0):

It simply means that the consumer has not received any records during that interval. The interval is checked after each poll that returns no records.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#idle-containers

If concurrency > 1, you would need to wait for each child container to emit the event.

> is it mean that no data has been produced to the topic

The consumer has no knowledge about the producer(s).

Comment: Ok dear just let me  bothering you with another deeper question as you said that the interval is checked after each poll that returns no record so let us assume the processing take about two minutes then no poll request will be, therefore no checking will happen  lead to not  capturing to the event .. is it like that ...l hope well explained

Comment: Yes; the interval includes the time taken to process the last poll that returned at least one record; if the following poll times out without returning any records, the event will be published at that time. You can always wait for 2 events, if that is not your desired behavior.